# ElasticSearch extended_bounds over range with no data/hitdocs

Tags: elasticsearch

I've a range for which no hitdocs exist. When a date_histogram aggregation based query is run with extended_bounds over this no-data range, nothing is returned.

However, for a range which has at least 1 hitdoc, buckets data is returned for the range as specified using extended_bounds.

How can I achieved similar results over a range with no hitdocs?

Sample query -

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "kind": "hit-search"
              }
            },
            {
              "range": {
                "startTime": {
                  "gte": 1506429661000,
                  "lte": 1506516061000
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "perHost": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "user"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "ts": {
          "date_histogram": {
            "field": "startTime",
            "interval": "30m",
            "min_doc_count": 0,
            "extended_bounds": {
              "min": 1506429661000,
              "max": 1506516061000
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "numQuery": {
              "cardinality": {
                "field": "queryId"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "from": 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One can use `missing` aggregation for the same. Above query looks like this after update -

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "kind": "hit-search"
              }
            },
            {
              "range": {
                "startTime": {
                  "gte": 1506429661000,
                  "lte": 1506516061000
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "perHost": {
      "missing": {
        "field": "user"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "ts": {
          "date_histogram": {
            "field": "startTime",
            "interval": "30m",
            "min_doc_count": 0,
            "extended_bounds": {
              "min": 1506429661000,
              "max": 1506516061000
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "numQuery": {
              "cardinality": {
                "field": "queryId"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "from": 0
}
```

An observation - `extended_bounds` doesn't seem to be working for `missing`.